# What location is recommended for installing Tor from sources?

Tags: software-installation, tor, unzip, location

I know how to install Tor browser from the sources and how to run it. But in all tutorial they don't mention where to unzip it and they always unzip into the ~/Downloads folder. But it's not a proper location for applications. So where should I unzip it, what location is recommended?

I know that I can unzip it everywhere, but my question isn't about where I can unzip it to, but where it's recommended. The user's folder, something like ~/apps? Or in /opt?

Comment: hi, if any of the given answers suffice as answer, pls mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest either of these ...

- inside your /home/$USER/ as a /home/$USER/tor{version}/.
- inside /opt/ as /opt/tor{version}/

The last one should be used on a multi-user system (you can then add users to a group that all can use it); otherwiseny  (single-user) pick any one of the two. The version is standard so you can put more than 1 next to each other and visually can see what version it is.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the home directory there are very little recommendations, about what to put where. In this particular case it's completely up to you. I would discourage you to put it in `/opt`.

The only 'standardized' folders of my knowing inside `/home/$USER` are `.local` `.config` and `.cache`. Like all `hidden folders` in `/home/$USER` - those with a dot infront - they hold user specific application settings and files. They can be shown in `nautilus` by pressing `Ctr-h`.

I would recommend to make the TorBrowser folder also an hidden one by editing it after unwrapping. After the first start of Tor Browser Bundle, dump a copy of the `Start TorBrowser` file to `~/local/share/applications/` this will allow you to find the TorBrowser in your application menu (unity,gnomeshell-activity, etc) and if running will display it as TorBrowser and not Firefox. Inside a terminal this can be done, after moving inside the TorBrowser folder via `cp start-tor-browser.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/start-tor-browser.desktop`.

As TorBrowser saves it's downloads inside it's own folder I made a bookmark inside nautilus called Townloads, for easier access.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the location on Manjaro Linux (Arch like).

> installation:
>
> > $HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser
>
> downloads:
>
> > $HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/Downloads/
>
> torrc (config file):
>
> > $HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc-defaults
> > $HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc
>
> profiles:
>
> > $HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/
>
> desktop launcher:
>
> > $HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/start-tor-browser.desktop